# Qual a melhor forma de representar uma FK no domínio

Tags: c#

Tenho por exemplo duas entidades no meu BD. Tipo_Usuario e Usuario.
Usuario recebe uma FK de Tipo_Usuario pelo campo IdTipoUsuario. No meu Domínio(C#) eu teria:

```
TipoUsuario
public int IDTipoUsuario { get; set; }
public string NmTipoUsuario { get; set; }
```

E na minha classe usuario teria

```
Usuario
public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
public string NmUsuario { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<int> IdTipoUsuario { get; set; }
```

Eu preciso também na tabela de TipoUsuario fazer isso

```
public virtual Usuario usuario { get; set; }
```

Apenas isso é ou suficiente para representar um chave estrangeira(FK) em minha classe ou preciso fazer mais?

Comment: Um usuário vai ter vários tipos ou um tipo vai ter vários usuários? Parece que tem um erro de conceito.

Comment: Usuário terá vários tipos, por isso eu fiz um ICollection em usuário

Comment: Mas um tipo (provavelmente) pode ter mais de um usuário.

Comment: @LINQ, sim, isso mesmo

Comment: então no `TipoUsuario` você também tem que ter uma ICollection]

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, eu só não vou precisar de **ICollection<>** em uma das pontas, quando eu tenho um **1:N**, certo? E onde entra a tabela associativa? Como eu a represento no meu domínio?